# Oauth2 for google api access in erlang

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, erlang, sql-grant

Hello I am writing code for oauth2 protocol for accessing google pub/sub api's . My code is as follows.

Method = post,

```
URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo",
Grant = "grant_type=authorization_code:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=&
        assertion=JWT_Token ",

Header = [{"Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}],
Body = [Grant],
Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
Options = [],
httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, [], Options).
```

I am getting following error when i send http request

```
Response{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",404,"Not Found"},
          [{"cache-control",
            "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"},
           {"date","Tue, 10 Nov 2015 22:27:36 GMT"},
           {"pragma","no-cache"},
           {"accept-ranges","none"},
           {"server","GSE"},
           {"vary","X-Origin"},
           {"content-length","9"},
           {"content-type","text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
           {"expires","Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"},
           {"x-content-type-options","nosniff"},
           {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
           {"x-xss-protection","1; mode=block"},
           {"alternate-protocol","443:quic,p=1"},
           {"alt-svc","quic=\":443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=604800"}],
          "Not Found"}}
```

I am almost sure the grant value i am sending is not correct.
I am not sure what parameter to pass in the URL and host parameters.
 Please help